# Django test DoesNotExist: Contact matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run my first test. The test fails with:

**DoesNotExist: Contact matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'mobile': '07000000000'}**

I seem to create user contact in the setup function so why is it not available?

Thanks

test.py

```
class BatchTestCase(TestCase):

    def setup(self):
         user = User.objects.get(username='glynjackson')
         contact = Contact.objects.get(mobile="07000000000", contact_owner=user, group=None)


    def test_get_contact(self):
        contact = Contact.objects.get(mobile='07000000000')
        self.assertEqual(contact.full_name(), 'Got Contact')
```

full error

```
ERROR: test_get_contact (sms.tests.test_sms_simulation.BatchTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/example/sms/tests/test_sms_simulation.py", line 18, in test_get_contact
    contact = Contact.objects.get(mobile='07000000000')
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/example/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/example/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 389, in get
    (self.model._meta.object_name, kwargs))
DoesNotExist: Contact matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'mobile': '07000000000'}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get` doesn't create record in the database and tries actually to get record. It founds no such record in the database and raises error DoesNotExist.

You should use something like:

```
contact = Contact(mobile="07000000000", contact_owner=user, group=None)
contact.save()
```

Answer (score 8):

You shall use `setUp` method, not `setup`. This method is called before running every test.

```
class BatchTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
         # create test objects here

    # ...
```